# Displaying the details (first name, surname ,email etc.) of the user currently logged into my power app

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, powerapp, powerapps-canvas, power-platform

I'm just wondering if it is possible to display the personal information of the user currently logged in an my 'User Profile' section of my app?

The first image attached is the current list I have created and the second image is the how I would like the information displayed.

Any help on how to get the personal information associated with the username and password to be displayed would be appreciated :)

**List**:

[image]

**App**:

[image]

Comment: Can you confirm - are you trying to show the current user information from "list" or from Azure Ad profile? If from list, what is the unique column in list using which you can identify the user, is it "Email"?

Comment: Hi Ganesh, yes I am trying to how the current user information from the "list". I am not sure what you mean by 'unique column', but I could use their email addresses to uniquely identify them. Thanks

Comment: Did you try below solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a "Form" control in your Power Apps to show the information, you can set the `Item` of form control with formula like this:

```
LookUp(SharePointListName, EmailColumnFromList = User().Email)
```

Use correct list name and column name in place of `SharePointListName` and `EmailColumnFromList` respectively.

Then you can set (or confirm) `Default` property of "Data card" controls inside the "Form" control to respective column values using formula like:

```
ThisItem.Title
```

and

```
ThisItem.password
```

---

You can also get the current user record from list in `OnStart` of `App` and store in global variable like:

```
Set(gvUserProfileFromList, LookUp(SharePointListName, EmailColumnFromList = User().Email))
```

Then later you can use this variable anywhere in the app.

**For example**: If you want to show the full name of user in a "label" control, then you can set the `Text` property of label control to:

```
gvUserProfileFromList.Firstname & " " & gvUserProfileFromList.Surname
```